# I can't subtract days from current_date parametrically in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to subtract some days from the current date and insert it into a table. If I write the number of days directly into the code it works. So this works.

```
do $$
DECLARE
    myDate Date;
BEGIN
    myDate = current_date - interval '10' day;
    insert into myTable (myDate) values (myDate);
end $$;
```

The problem is that I want to put the number of days in a variable to make it parametric. But I can't. In fact the following doesn't work:

```
do $$
DECLARE
    myDate Date;
    daysAgo character varying := '10';
BEGIN
    myDate = current_date - interval daysAgo day;
    insert into myTable (myDate) values (myDate);
end $$;
```

Comment: `myDate := current_date - daysago;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract a number of days (integer) from a date:

```
do $$
DECLARE
    myDate Date;
    daysAgo int := 10;
BEGIN
    myDate = current_date - daysAgo;
    insert into myTable (myDate) values (myDate);
end $$;
```

[Date/Time Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you need to do this not just for days, you can do certain math operations on intervals:

```
do $$
declare
  minutes int4 := 34;
begin
raise notice '%', interval '1 minute' * minutes;
raise notice '%', interval '15 minute' / minutes;
end;
$$;
-- outpus:
-- 00:34:00
-- 00:00:26.470588
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works (with the `make_interval` function) but is more verbouse than Klin's solution.

```
do $$
DECLARE
    myDate Date;
    daysAgo int := 10;
BEGIN
    myDate = current_date - make_interval(days=>daysAgo);
    insert into myTable (myDate) values (myDate);
end $$;
```